# Power BI Slicer should not filter complete table

Tags: powerbi

I have a below scenario in which i have a location slicer which filters the table perfectly.

[Current Situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTi2D.png)

What i required is when location is selected in slicer it should show All location but filtered values as 0.

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8GfF.png)

How can i achieve this in power BI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a new table **Location** with all distinct locations like the following:

[image]

And create a relationship like this:

[image]

Use the Location column from the Location table to create the slicer.
Finally use the following dax function to create a measure:

```
Measure = 
VAR __location = SELECTEDVALUE( 'Location Table'[Location] )
VAR __flag = COUNTROWS( 'Location Table' ) 
Return 
IF( 
    __flag > 1,
    SUM( 'Table'[Values] ),
    IF(
        SELECTEDVALUE( 'Table'[Location] ) = __location,
        SUM( 'Table'[Values] ),
        0 
    ) 
)
```

This is the expected result:

[image]